# Write to a CD from .Net

Tags: .net, autorun, cd-burning

Is there an easy way to write to a CD from .Net? How about creating a multisession CD that autoruns an executable that writes to itself?

Comment: Which version of .NET, by the way?  That might be useful...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this via the [ICDBurn interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776155(VS.85).aspx).

See [this article for details](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/tipstricks/article.php/c15201).

Comment: I used this for a simple backup to cd system for my mother. Worked a charm. Multisession disks are no problem, and you could create the initial disk with the autorun and executable on it without too much effort.

Answer (score 1):

[IMAPI is what you want.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364806(VS.85).aspx)  There are [.net wrappers](http://www.ohloh.net/p/imapi-net), but I've never used [any of them](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/net/code/libraries/writing_cds/imapi/article.asp).

Answer (score 1):

IMAPI2.  In short, no, there is no easy way to write to a CD from within .NET.

Answer (score 0):

[Burning and Erasing CD/DVD/Blu-ray Media with C# and IMAPI2 @ codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24544/Burning-and-Erasing-CD-DVD-Blu-ray-Media-with-C-an)