# Is it possible to write to a CD with .NET?

Tags: .net, file-io, cd-burning

I have a data file in f:\ drive named 'cd.txt'.
I want to write this file to a CD i.e E:\.

```
String source ="F:\\cd.txt";
String destination="E:\\cd.txt";

File.copy(sorce,destination);
```

The above line is throwing exception saying:

> "Access to the path 'E:\cd.txt' is denied"

Comment: Is the .NET/C#? You can use ICDBurn to copy files to a disc. See this answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799867/write-to-a-cd-from-net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799867/write-to-a-cd-from-net)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's so easily feasible, Windows explorer give the impression doing a file copy is enough but that not the case.

I think you might take a look at [XPBurn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336741.aspx) component.

Answer (score 0):

You cant just copy files to a disc drive. Writing files to a CD-R is a complicated process.

I have heard of a C# .NET component called [XPBurn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336741.aspx). I have not used it, but it looks like it'll do what you need using the [IMAPI Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366216%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it's technically Windows API:

[Dhawan the One](http://blogs.msdn.com/dhawan/archive/2009/11/17/introduction-to-imapi.aspx)

Comment: why is that exception thrown? What is the solution?

Comment: You're trying to treat the drive as a normal read-write drive... I suspect you have to 'prep' the drive before you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

IMAPI is only for C++, is there a good wrapper for C#? o maybe a library? i used the project wrapper from the codeproject page.. i haven't test it, all i did was exclude the Interop folder and moved it to another project to try and build the winform in WPF.. therefore i excluded the Interop to a single class project for a DLL... will test it this week..