# Suggestions on how to burn cds programmatically

Tags: c#, cd-burning

I am writing an application in C# in which I need to burn a cd programmatically.  I am on a bit of a time crunch and haven't had any luck finding an easy way to do so.  Can someone please suggest the easiest/quickest way to do this?

Comment: Hi - check out this similar question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799867/write-to-a-cd-from-net

Answer (score 1):

You could use IMAPIv2 for a quick solution. I have this example code I downloaded a while ago... can't remember where I downloaded it from but I don't take credit for the code. Hope it helps.

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using IMAPI2;
using ifs = IMAPI2FS;
using MSDN.Samples.Imapi2;

namespace Demo3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // prepare the CFileSystemImage object and the event sink
            ifs.CFileSystemImage image = new IMAPI2FS.CFileSystemImage();
            CFileSystemImageEventHelper helper = new CFileSystemImageEventHelper(image);
            helper.Update += new IMAPI2FS.DFileSystemImageEvents_UpdateEventHandler(helper_Update);

            // Add some files to the image
            // Substitute with the path to your actual data
            image.Root.AddTree(@"c:\users\username\data", false);

            // Initialize a disc recorder
            string recorderID = new MsftDiscMaster2Class()[0];
            MsftDiscRecorder2Class recorder = new MsftDiscRecorder2Class();
            recorder.InitializeDiscRecorder(recorderID);

            // Prepare the DiscFormat2Data object
            MsftDiscFormat2DataClass fmtObj = new MsftDiscFormat2DataClass();
            // This is a workaround to address a type casting problem specific to .NET
            IDiscFormat2Data2 fmt = (IDiscFormat2Data2)fmtObj;
            fmtObj.Recorder = recorder;
            DDiscFormat2DataEventHelper fmtHelper = new DDiscFormat2DataEventHelper((MsftDiscFormat2DataClass)fmt);
            fmtHelper.Update += new DDiscFormat2DataEventHelper_UpdateEventHandler(fmtHelper_Update);
            ifs.IStream stm = image.CreateResultImage().ImageStream;

            // Write data
            fmt.Write((System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream)stm);
        }

        static void fmtHelper_Update(IDiscFormat2Data @object, IDiscFormat2DataEventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: Elapsed: {1}, Estimated: {2}", args.CurrentAction, args.ElapsedTime, args.TotalTime);
        }

        static void helper_Update(object @object, string currentFile, int copiedSectors, int totalSectors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Adding " + currentFile);
        }
    }

    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    [ComImport, Guid("2735413B-8F64-4B0F-8F00-5D77AFBE261E")]
    public interface IDiscFormat2Data2
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x888)]
        bool IsRecorderSupported([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IDiscRecorder2 Recorder);
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x777)]
        bool IsCurrentMediaSupported([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IDiscRecorder2 Recorder);
        [DispId(0x100)]
        IDiscRecorder2 Recorder { [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x100)] get; [param: In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x100)] set; }
        [DispId(0x101)]
        bool BufferUnderrunFreeDisabled { [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x101)] get; [param: In] [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x101)] set; }
        [DispId(260)]
        bool PostgapAlreadyInImage { [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(260)] get; [param: In] [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(260)] set; }
        [DispId(0x105)]
        object[] SupportedMediaTypes { [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_VARIANT)] [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x105)] get; }
        [ComAliasName("imapi2.Interop.IMAPI_FORMAT2_DATA_MEDIA_STATE"), DispId(0x106)]
        IMAPI2.IMAPI_FORMAT2_DATA_MEDIA_STATE CurrentMediaStatus { [return: ComAliasName("imapi2.Interop.IMAPI_FORMAT2_DATA_MEDIA_STATE")] [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x106)] get; }
        [DispId(0x107), ComAliasName("imapi2.Interop.IMAPI_MEDIA_WRITE_PROTECT_STATE")]
        IMAPI2.IMAPI_MEDIA_WRITE_PROTECT_STATE WriteProtectStatus { [return: ComAliasName("imapi2.Interop.IMAPI_MEDIA_WRITE_PROTECT_STATE")] [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x107)] get; }
        [DispId(0x108)]
        int TotalSectorsOnMedia { [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x108)] get; }
        [DispId(0x109)]
        int FreeSectorsOnMedia { [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x109)] get; }
        [DispId(0x10a)]
        int NextWritableAddress { [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x10a)] get; }
        [DispId(0x10b)]
        int StartAddressOfPreviousSession { [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x10b)] get; }
        [DispId(0x10c)]
        int LastWrittenAddressOfPreviousSession { [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x10c)] get; }
        [DispId(0x10d)]
        bool ForceMediaToBeClosed { [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x10d)] get; [param: In] [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x10d)] set; }
        [DispId(270)]
        bool DisableConsumerDvdCompatibilityMode { [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(270)] get; [param: In] [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(270)] set; }
        [ComAliasName("imapi2.Interop.IMAPI_MEDIA_PHYSICAL_TYPE"), DispId(0x10f)]
        IMAPI2.IMAPI_MEDIA_PHYSICAL_TYPE CurrentPhysicalMediaType { [return: ComAliasName("imapi2.Interop.IMAPI_MEDIA_PHYSICAL_TYPE")] [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x10f)] get; }
        [DispId(0x110)]
        string ClientName { [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x110)] get; [param: In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x110)] set; }
        [DispId(0x111)]
        uint RequestedWriteSpeed { [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x111)] get; }
        [DispId(0x112)]
        bool RequestedRotationTypeIsPureCAV { [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x112)] get; }
        [DispId(0x113)]
        uint CurrentWriteSpeed { [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x113)] get; }
        [DispId(0x114)]
        bool CurrentRotationTypeIsPureCAV { [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x114)] get; }
        [DispId(0x115)]
        object[] SupportedWriteSpeeds { [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_VARIANT)] [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x115)] get; }
        [DispId(0x116)]
        object[] SupportedWriteSpeedDescriptors { [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_VARIANT)] [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x116)] get; }
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x200)]
        void Write([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream data);
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x201)]
        void CancelWrite();
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x202)]
        void SetWriteSpeed([In] uint RequestedSectorsPerSecond, [In] bool RotationTypeIsPureCAV);
    }

}
```